# xslt apply template on sorted data

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, filter

i'm new with xslt transformation and i'm having some trouble with it.
I need to both sort and filter elements, in the following example I managed to sort and filter the input xml with two xlt transformations.
My question is: how to both sort and then filter sorted data with a single xsl file?
Thanks in advance.

XML input:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <id>00000_1111_2222</id>
        <startedAt>2017-08-21T11:55:08.382Z</startedAt>
        <endedAt>2017-08-21T12:07:08.539Z</endedAt>
        <positions>
            <timestamp>2017-08-21T11:55:28.041Z</timestamp>
            <latitude>40.2407009</latitude>
            <longitude>10.7750499</longitude>     
        </positions>
        <positions>
            <timestamp>2017-08-21T11:55:28.041Z</timestamp>
            <latitude>40.2409364</latitude>
            <longitude>10.7748426</longitude>
        </positions>
        <positions>
            <timestamp>2017-08-21T11:55:38.041Z</timestamp>
            <latitude>40.240409</latitude>
            <longitude>10.7751432</longitude>    
        </positions>
    </data>
</root>
```

XSL Sorting:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::positions)]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="positions">
                <xsl:sort select="timestamp" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL Filtering:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::positions)]" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="positions[position() &lt;= 4]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i would preserve original xmlstructure, is it corret this xsl?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Sort and filter positions elements -->
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="positions">
                <xsl:sort select="timestamp" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 2">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output XML would be:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <data>
        <id>00000_1111_2222</id>
        <startedAt>2017-08-21T11:55:08.382Z</startedAt>
        <endedAt>2017-08-21T12:07:08.539Z</endedAt>
        
      <positions>
         <timestamp>2017-08-21T11:55:38.041Z</timestamp>
         <latitude>40.240409</latitude>
         <longitude>10.7751432</longitude>
      </positions>
      <positions>
         <timestamp>2017-08-21T11:55:28.041Z</timestamp>
         <latitude>40.2407009</latitude>
         <longitude>10.7750499</longitude>
      </positions>
   </data>
</root>
```

But in this way i loose all elements not child of "positions" elements: id, startedAt, endedAt.
So i tried to add: `<xsl:apply-templates select="*` [not(self::positions)]"/> after `<xsl:template match="data">` and it works, but what about if all NOT "position" childs, are after the positions elements? in this way i will loose original xml structure/order. Is there a way to achieve this last thing in a generic way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted-positions" as="element(positions)*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="positions">
    <xsl:sort select="timestamp" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then `<xsl:copy-of select="$sorted-positions[position() le 4]"/>` (or an apply-templates on those elements of course).

Or you can use e.g.

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="positions">
            <xsl:sort select="timestamp" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
```

and then

```
<xsl:template match="positions">
  <xsl:if test="position() le 4">
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you could of course use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="positions">
  <xsl:sort select="timestamp" order="descending"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 4">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

also of course having there the choice of using `copy-of` instead of the `apply-templates`.

Finally, with XSLT 3.0 and support for the `sort` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sort) you can directly `apply-templates` on the sorted sequence (or in your case, on the `reverse`d sorted sequence to have order as descending) and filtered sequence:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except positions, reverse(sort(positions, (), function($p) { $p/timestamp}))[position() le 4]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank You for yor great answer, just one thing: if i would keep the original xml file structure? how to preserver others nodes? I will put an example in edit

Comment: Well, your original approach as well as your comment has one way, namely to put an additional `apply-templates` where you want to process the other child nodes. As for a more generic solution, I think it is better if you ask a new question showing some input samples, I think we need to see in what variations the input can exist (content before and/or after `positions`, content mixed with `positions`) and how you then want to reorder the elements (all `positions` together?). Please also state clearly whether you can use XSLT 2.0.